# How to prove $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\binom{n}{i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i}i = np$?

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions

How to prove, when $p\in[0, 1]$,

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\binom{n}{i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i}i = np$$

Is there a name for this formula?

Comment: You need $n-i$ in place of $i$ in one of the exponents.  The formula gives the expected value of a binomial distribution, so you will find it in most textbooks on probability and statistics.

Comment: I think is $(1-p)^{n-i}$

Comment: @Tad My bad. Updated.

Answer (score 5):

Indirect route:

If $X$ is binomially distributed with parameters $n$ and $p$ then we can write $X=X_1+\cdots+X_n$ where the $X_i$ are iid Bernouilli-$p$. We can find $\mathbb EX$ by means of: $$\mathbb EX=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb P(X=i).i=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\binom{n}{i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i}i$$ and also by means of: $$\mathbb EX=\mathbb EX_1+\cdots+\mathbb EX_n=np$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint
$$i\binom{n}{i}=n\binom{n-1}{i-1}$$
then we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i\binom{n}{i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i}=np\sum_{i=1}^{n}\binom{n-1}{i-1}p^{i-1}(1-p)^{n-i}=np(p+1-p)^{n-1}=np$$

Answer (score 1):

Still another approach:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\binom{n}{i}i x^{i-1}(1-p)^{n-i}&=&\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\binom{n}{i}x^i(1-p)^{n-i}=\frac{d}{dx}(x+1-p)^{n}\\&=&n(x+1-p)^{n-1}\tag{1}\end{eqnarray*}$$ 
so by plugging in $x=p$, then multiplying both sides by $p$, we prove our claim.